# Creating custom menu at top like Real Simple Recipes does

Tags: iphone, ipad, tabbarcontroller

I want to create tabbar controller placed at the top like [Real Simple Recipes in iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-simple-recipes-no-time/id409351090?mt=8) has done. I suspect that it is not UITabBarController as I have tried so many ways to place tab bar on the top by setting its view frame as

`self.tabBarController.tabBar.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,768,self.tabBarController.tabBar.view.frame.height);`
But it is not working.

Is it custom tabbar controller created or it is managed manually ? Any sample code or direction would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a custom view switcher of your own. [This blog post](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited) has a nice tutorial for doing so. It uses a segmented control to do the switching, but you could adapt it to use a row of buttons if you needed a custom look.

(If you are OK requiring iOS 5, this gets easier with the view controller containment APIs, and it'd be a completely different implementation to the one suggested in that article.)